# asking user same thing without program is terminated c++

Tags: c++

my program is asking user to answer sum of 2 random numbers ,if answer is correct output is "good" and when its not correct "try again". But i want the program keep asking question again and again my program terminates when user answer it ,can you help me?

I want the output be like

```
How much is 19 plus 7 (-1 to End)?: 25
No - Please try again: 26
Very good!
How much is 9 plus 12 (-1 to End)?: 21
Very good!
How much is 71 plus 15 (-1 to End)?: 1
No - Please try again: 86
Very good!
How much is 17 plus 33 (-1 to End)?: -1
```

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number1,number2, answer;
    int x=0 ;
    srand(time(NULL));
    number1 = rand() % 100 + 1;
    number2 = rand() % 100 + 1;

    x=number1 + number2;



        cout << "What is the " << number1 << " plus " << number2 << " ?" << endl;

        cin >> answer;

        if (answer!=x)
            cout << "No,Please try again.";

        else
        cout << "Very good!";

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you want is a loop.

Comment: Your going to need a [`while`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_while_loop.htm) loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    int number1, number2, answer;
    int x = 0;
    srand (time(NULL));
    do
    {
        number1 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        number2 = rand() % 100 + 1;

        x = number1 + number2;

        cout << "What is the " << number1 << " plus " << number2 << " ?"  << endl;

        cin >> answer;

        if (answer == -1)
            continue;
        if (answer != x)
            cout << "No,Please try again.";

        else
            cout << "Very good!";

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
    } while (answer != -1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , i tried do while loop but i was just confuced what to write in bracles of while , now i understand the logic , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this at the place of your if else conditions

```
    while(answer!=x)
    {    cout<<"no! please try again";
         cin>>answer;
    }
   cout<<"good";
```